# Is it possible to disable frictionless payments in facebook?

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3

We are currently using facebook credits and frictionless payments work as expected. As part of the migration to local currency and the phase out of credits, we have introduced our own virtual currency and invoke the facebook payment dialog to buy currency from AS3 as follows:

```
        var data : Object = new Object();

        data["credits_purchase"] = false;
        data["method"] = "pay.prompt";
        data["order_info"] = product;
        data["purchase_type"] = "item";
        data["dev_purchase_params"] = {"oscif":true};

        Facebook.ui("pay", data, onPayCallback, "iframe");
```

This works fine when the user has no facebook credits, and displays a purchase dialog with the user's local currency.

However, when the user has a credits balance then this is automatically used in preference to local currency (which is ok) BUT no purchase dialog is displayed and a frictionless payment takes place (if the transaction is < 30 credits). A 'purchase complete' dialog is displayed but the user has no choice in the matter.

Is it possible to disable frictionless payments so that the user experience is consistent between local currency and credits during the phase out?